# how to fix this react-native "uncaught error"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile

after that i start the code it shows an error

tried to delete some lines, or change some values but it seems to keep to appear anyway.

at the console(f12) after i start the app with:

```
expo-cli start --tunnel
```

i get this error:

> caught Error: Cannot find module 'undefined'
> at webpackMissingModule (entry.js:7:1)
> at ./node_modules/expo-router/entry.js (entry.js:7:1)
> at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:24:1)
> at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
> at ./index.js (log.js:59:1)
> at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:24:1)
> at startup:6:1
> at startup:6:1

how can i infer from that error any kind of data that can help me figure it out?
and how do i solve this? currently there is only basic index page that look like this:

```
import { View,Text } from "react-native";
const Home = ()=>{
    // const router = useRouter()
    return
    <SafeAreaView>
        <Text>home</Text>
    </SafeAreaView> 
    
}

export default Home;
```

and it doesnt even show the "home" text